# Creating partition tables on USB ATA drives fails with fdisk and KDE partitionmanager

Tags: partition, fdisk

I have a couple old ATA (yes, not SATA) hard drive around with USB enclosures. One of them gave me some EXT4 journal error, so I am not sure whether they have a physical problem. Since they are just backup disks, I want to put a new btrfs onto them.

## fdisk

I tried to do this with `fdisk`. To clean them completely, I want a new partition table, in case there was a problem in there.

```
env LC_ALL=C sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

This is the current state of one of the disk:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00006dd0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Then I create a new partition table:

```
Command (m for help): o
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x20bf4f51.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)
```

This warning comes every time with every disk. The value of the flag might differ, though. Now I print the partition table again:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x20bf4f51

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

That is still empty, fine.

Create a new partition:

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): 
Using default response p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
Using default value 1
First sector (2048-312581807, default 2048): 
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-312581807, default 312581807): 
Using default value 312581807
```

There should now be a partition that spans the whole disk. When I check with `p` again, there is a partition.

Write it:

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

Error closing file
```

I am a little clueless on this. I used `dd` to write 400M of zeros onto the first part of the disks, but that did not change anything.

## KDE Partition Manager

This is the original state of the disk:

[image]

Now I want to create a new partition table:

[image]

[image]

Create a new partition in the unallocated area:

[image]

[image]

Write changes to disk:

[image]

Unhelpful error message:

[image]

---

I am a little stuck here, I have no idea why I cannot just reformat the disks to my liking.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Looking at this, you did quite everything you could. I would suspect hardware failure. I would suggest to try badblocks or some other tool to check the disk health, also try to read the SMART data using smartctl or something else.

Comment: I was able to format the harddrive with Windows 8, though. And after I changed it to GPT there, I was able to format it again with `gdisk`.